# Rails 3.1 - Saving Multiple Models with Dates

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a nested form set up that will allow me to create up to 7 "Schedule" instances at one time.  Each instance will allow a user to assign a schedule_start_time(datetime), schedule_end_time(datetime), and notes(String) field value.  When I submit the form with a few of these completed, the parameters array looks exactly as I would expect:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"HEoylzovRgr7BCZH47iNRPfizDHeVFMLTEmIiNeudcw=",
>   "workout"=>{"id"=>"2",
>   "schedules_attributes"=>{
>
> "0"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"06/01/2011",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"06/02/2011",
>   "notes"=>"Notes 1"},
>
> "1"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"",
>   "notes"=>""},
>
> "2"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"06/03/2011",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"06/04/2011",
>   "notes"=>"Notes 2"},
>
> "3"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"",
>   "notes"=>""},
>
> "4"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"06/16/2011",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"06/30/2011",
>   "notes"=>"Notes 3"},
>
> "5"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"",
>   "notes"=>""},
>
> "6"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"",
>   "notes"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

In the controller, I filter those "schedules" with a blank start_date. My params list then looks like this:

> {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"HEoylzovRgr7BCZH47iNRPfizDHeVFMLTEmIiNeudcw=",
>   "workout"=>{"id"=>"2",
>   "schedules_attributes"=>{
>
> "0"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"06/01/2011",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"06/02/2011",
>   "notes"=>"Notes 1"},
>
> "2"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"06/03/2011",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"06/04/2011",
>   "notes"=>"Notes 2"},
>
> "4"=>{"scheduled_start_time"=>"06/16/2011",
>   "scheduled_end_time"=>"06/30/2011",
>   "notes"=>"Notes 3"}}},
>
> "commit"=>"Submit",
>   "action"=>"create",
>   "controller"=>"schedules"}

The SQL that gets generaated is not what I would expect however:

> (0.1ms)  BEGIN WARNING: Can't
>   mass-assign protected attributes: id
>
> SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `schedules`
>   (`created_at`, `notes`,
>   `scheduled_end_time`,
>   `scheduled_start_time`, `updated_at`,
>   `workout_id`) VALUES ('2011-06-29
>   03:23:45', 'Notes 1', '2011-02-06
>   00:00:00', '2011-01-06 00:00:00',
>   '2011-06-29 03:23:45', 2)
>
> SQL
>   (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `schedules`
>   (`created_at`, `notes`,
>   `scheduled_end_time`,
>   `scheduled_start_time`, `updated_at`,
>   `workout_id`) VALUES ('2011-06-29
>   03:23:45', 'Notes 2', '2011-04-06
>   00:00:00', '2011-03-06 00:00:00',
>   '2011-06-29 03:23:45', 2)
>
> SQL
>   (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `schedules`
>   (`created_at`, `notes`,
>   `scheduled_end_time`,
>   `scheduled_start_time`, `updated_at`,
>   `workout_id`) VALUES ('2011-06-29
>   03:23:45', 'Notes 3', NULL, NULL,
>   '2011-06-29 03:23:45', 2)    (0.5ms) 
>   COMMIT

Some of the valid date values are in the params array, but are being filtered out before the SQL commits.

Here is the controller code:

```
  def create
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:workout][:id])

    7.times do |count|
      @schedule = params[:workout][:schedules_attributes]["#{count}"]
      if (@schedule[:scheduled_start_time].blank?)
        params[:workout][:schedules_attributes].delete count.to_s.to_sym
      end
    end

    if @workout.update_attributes(params[:workout])
      redirect_to schedules_url, :notice  => "Successfully updated schedule."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

And the Workout Model

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_id"
has_many :exercise_instances, :dependent => :destroy

validates :name,
          :presence => true

has_many :schedules, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules

end
```

And the Schedule Model

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :workout_id, :scheduled_start_time, :scheduled_end_time, :notes
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

Any direction would be welcome.  I'm suspecting caching at some level, but I'm just not sure where to start looking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are reinventing the wheel here and it's the source of the problem. Try the following:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules, :dependent => :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |schedule| schedule[:scheduled_start_time].blank? }
end
```

You will still need to restrict the number of schedules to 7. I would recommend checking out existing solutions for this behavior; there are a lot of solid patterns on this already.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @coreyward,  This definitely looks cleaner than what I have and I'll put it to use.  I ended up reconstructing the solution so that I didn't need the nesting.  In the process of doing that, I realized that **my date was not being parsed correctly.  The system thought I was using DD/MM/YYYY as opposed to MM/DD/YYYY.  As a result, dates where the second digit was greater than 12 were getting rejected.**  All is well now.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do something like

```
params[:workout][:schedules_attributes].each do |sched|
  @workout.schedules << @workout.schedules.build(sched) if sched[:scheduled_start_time].present?
end

if @workout.save # etc
```

And not use nested_attributes_for. This will guarantee that you will only get what was sent.

I've found with nested_attributes that it's often best to delete and recreate on edit every time as well, which may or may not be what you want.

I'm sure others with better nested_attributes 'fu' than me may have better solutions.